# Can't install node-sass because mkdirp not found

Tags: npm, node-sass

I get error that module 'mkdirp' not found..

I installed it, it listed in package.json:
    `"mkdirp": "^0.5.1"`

```
dev@b7ee560044f1:~/project$ npm i -D node-sass@4.5.3

> node-sass@4.5.3 install /home/dev/project/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

module.js:550
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'mkdirp'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/dev/volume/cache/front-node-modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:7:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/webpack/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.5.3 install: `node scripts/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.5.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/dev/.npm/_logs/2019-01-14T16_08_27_969Z-debug.log
dev@b7ee560044f1:~/project$ npm i -D node-sass@4.5.3
```

Why this error happens? 
I don't understand how npm works...

Answer (score 0):

Ok , first try to install the latest version of this package and then try again to install node-sass.

so run this `npm install mkdirp@latest` and then try again.

Is that working?

Comment: 0.5.1 is latest version. your advice didn't help. https://github.com/substack/node-mkdirp/releases

Answer (score 0):

This got the mkdirp installed:

```
 $ npm install -g mkdirp@latest
```